# How to keep the values filled in a form and recover after navigating to another controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am facing this situation. I have a form that I filled with three values. Then by clicking on a button I'm in another controller and I create an XmlDocument object I recovered via TempData. Once completed action coming back to my form naturally when all data has disappeared. My question is, how do I fill out the form, keep these values, and once the XML created to fill my database with the form data and XML created.

Layout controller

```
public class LayoutController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var Layout = new LayoutModel();
        return View(Layout);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(LayoutModel Layout)
    {
        if (Layout == null)
        {
            return Content("le LayoutModel est nul");
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["DocName"] = Layout.Nom;         
            if (TempData["xmlAssociated"] != null)
            {
                Layout.xmlAssociated = (string)TempData["xmlAssociated"];
                ManageXML.Models.COracleConn.GetInstance().InsertLayout(Layout);
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("On a pas recuperé l'XML");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("ListOfTopsAndMarges", "Entete_Marge");
        }
    }
}
```

XMLRecord controller

```
public class XMLRecordController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult HandleForm()
    {
        var file = new XMLRecord()
        {
            Records = new List<XMLRecord>(){ new XMLRecord(){ Type="", Contenu="" }}
        };
        return View(file);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult HandleForm(XMLRecord file)
    {
        if (file == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            file.DocName = (string)TempData["DocName"];
            string recup = file.GenerateXML(file);
            TempData["xmlAssociated"] = recup;
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Layout");
        }         
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the LayoutModel and tell us what properties you need remembered. Essentially you need to let your Create() method take over the properties and change the HandleForm(XMLRecord file)'s RedirectToAction to pass over the arguements

Answer (score 0):

```html
public class LayoutModel
    {



        public string Nom { get; set; }


        public string Type { get; set; }


        public string Contenu { get; set; }

        public string xmlAssociated {get; set;}
```

}

I want to retain my Type, my Contenu and my Nom properties even if I am going to another controller

Thnak for your help @Heymega